# How to load mvt tiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, vector-tiles

I want to load mvt tiles into QGIS through a URL service

> https://abc.com:8080/buildings/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt

But, the menu in the **Vector Tile Reader plugin** allows TileJSON URL.

Is there any way I can load mvt tiles in QGIS environment?

Comment: What happens when you put that URL into the plugin?

Comment: Returns the following error.
"The field ''vector_layers' is required but not found. This is invalid TileJSON.

Comment: what format are your Map Vector Tiles?

Comment: @nmtoken tiles are in pbf format.

Comment: Wrote my own script to decode and display mapbox vector tiles parsed as pbf in QGIS. Closing...

Comment: @raosaeedali was writing your own script the only way of viewing the MVT in QGIS in the end?

Comment: @JoshuaDickerson In my case, sadly, yes. Tried the above mentioned plugin but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @raosaeedali , I'm facing the same problem. Could I ask how do you parse the pbf with qgis's python?

Comment: @OscarCampo see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    r = requests.get(url)

    # ------------------------Decryption------------------------
    response = r.content
    decoded_data = mapbox_vector_tile.decode(response)
```

Import relevant modules to your sript, parse the URL to your specific tile at specific zoom level for example;

```
https://abc.com:8080/buildings/16/4059/6568.mvt
```

Here 16/4059/6568 are zoom level X and Y numbers of your requested tile id.
After that you can print `decoded data` to see the decoded JSON of your tile.

Comment: Great, thank you. I didn't hope that the mapbox_vector_tile module was in qgis's python

Comment: @OscarCampo No it was not. You have to load it using Pip.