# QGIS load tiles from GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, vector-tiles

I use QGIS 3.10 as GIS client and i would like to be able to load tiles served from GeoServer.
I've well installed the Vector Tiles extension in GeoServer, my layers are well served when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/`.
I've installed the extension Vector Tiles Reader in QGIS.
However, when I add my url in Vector Tiles (add layer) i've got an error `The field 'vector_layers' is required but not found. This is invalid TileJSON`

Comment: Can you test out a different type of connection to Geoserver? Like just a simple WMS or similar?Just to eliminate any weird connection issues you might be having (local host though so shouldn't be).

Comment: Also maybe try this thread? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267376/how-to-load-mvt-tiles-in-qgis?rq=1

Comment: QGIS has native vector tiles support starting from 3.14. It may not resolve your problem but I recommend to upgrade anyway.

Comment: No problem about a weired connection. All works well. We can't upgrade to QGIS 3.14... Because we have to make a new install to 100 people.